# Shiny: overlapping of renderPlot with fluidrow

Tags: r, plot, shiny, overlapping

In the Shiny example http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-plus-three-columns.html if we replace the code part in `server.R`

```
print(p)

})
```

by

```
print(p)

}, height = 600)
```

we get an overlapping of the graphic window and the inputs below integrated with `fluidrow`.
How can we avoid such an overlapping when `height` is specified in `renderPlot` ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the plot a UI object, then the size will be known when it renders. I made the plot size a slider, which is optional of course :)

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

dataset <- diamonds

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  title = "Diamonds Explorer",

  uiOutput('sized_plot'),

  hr(),

  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           h4("Diamonds Explorer"),
           sliderInput('sampleSize', 'Sample Size', 
                       min=1, max=nrow(dataset),
                       value=min(1000, nrow(dataset)), 
                       step=500, round=0),
           sliderInput('plotSize', 'Plot Size', 
                       min=100, max=2000,
                       value=600, 
                       step=50, round=0),
           br(),
           checkboxInput('jitter', 'Jitter'),
           checkboxInput('smooth', 'Smooth')
    ),
    column(4, offset = 1,
           selectInput('x', 'X', names(dataset)),
           selectInput('y', 'Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[2]]),
           selectInput('color', 'Color', c('None', names(dataset)))
    ),
    column(4,
           selectInput('facet_row', 'Facet Row',
                       c(None='.', names(diamonds[sapply(diamonds, is.factor)]))),
           selectInput('facet_col', 'Facet Column',
                       c(None='.', names(diamonds[sapply(diamonds, is.factor)])))
    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataset <- reactive({
    diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), input$sampleSize),]
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    p <- ggplot(dataset(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + geom_point()

    if (input$color != 'None')
      p <- p + aes_string(color=input$color)

    facets <- paste(input$facet_row, '~', input$facet_col)
    if (facets != '. ~ .')
      p <- p + facet_grid(facets)

    if (input$jitter)
      p <- p + geom_jitter()
    if (input$smooth)
      p <- p + geom_smooth()

    print(p)

  })

  output$sized_plot <- renderUI({
    plotOutput("plot", height = input$plotSize)
  })

})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution made me understand that the solution was simpler in fact : just use the `height` argument of the `plotOutput` function instead of using  the `height` argument of the `renderPlot` function....